Ibis to Sql using ibis.tosql()
I want Query to be in this format
SELECT
    u.name,
    nicknames AS nickname
  FROM
    `india.nvidia.user_table` u,
    UNNEST(nicknames) AS nicknames
    WHERE u.l is true


my py file
import ibis

region='india'
account='nvidia'
# Create a dummy table
user_profile = ibis.table({
    'name': 'string',
    'nicknames':'array<string>',
    'l': 'boolean'
}, name=f'{region}.{account}.user_table')


unnested = user_profile.mutate(nickname=user_profile.nicknames.unnest())

filtered = unnested[unnested.l == True]

result = filtered[['name','nickname']]

print(ibis.to_sql(result))

Not getting the exact match can someone help me out here?
Trying to convert ibis to sql for better multiple execution.
Anyone with the knowledge would be a great help.

Can you try the following:
import ibis

region = 'india'
account = 'nvidia'

user_profile = ibis.table({
    'name': 'string',
    'nicknames': 'array<string>',
    'l': 'boolean'
}, name=f'{region}.{account}.user_table')

unnested = user_profile.mutate(nickname=user_profile.nicknames.unnest())

filtered = unnested[unnested.l]

result = filtered[['name', 'nickname']]

sql_query = ibis.to_sql(result)
print(sql_query)



Output:-
SELECT   "t1"."name",   "t1"."nickname" FROM (   SELECT     "t0"."name",     "t0"."nicknames",     "t0"."l",     UNNEST("t0"."nicknames") AS "nickname"   FROM "india.nvidia.user_table" AS "t0" ) AS "t1" WHERE   "t1"."l" = TRUE

isn't the expected output ?

Nope...I think we can't unnest like the above output in BQ. unnest should be after from..Like the output I want in the question itself!
